# Need to resize banner to fit window CSS

Tags: html, css, image, resize, banner

I am trying to make my site logo/banner fit the content box correctly. 
Unfortunately, it is appearing at different widths on different computer resolutions and window sizes.

This is also happening with my banner ad within the content box.

**CSS**

```
#logo {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    width: auto; 
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="logo">
    <center>
        <img src="logo.png" alt="Image of Traffic Monsoon">
    </center>
</div>
```

[The website is here.](http://clubtrafficmonsoon.com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<center>`is deprecated so **don't** use it.

To fix your issue you need to target the `img` not the `div`

use `margin:auto` and `display:block` to center the image instead of the deprecated `center`

```css
#logo img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
  margin:auto;
  display:block
}
```

```html
<div id="logo">
  <a>
    <img src="http://clubtrafficmonsoon.com/banner.gif" alt="Image of Traffic Monsoon">
  </a>
</div>
```

If you want to apply this generally to all images in the site,  just do this:

```css
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the help, unfortunately now the banner is coming up aligned on the left after removing centre tag. Any ideas?

Comment: everything is working perfectly apart from the banner size now

Answer (score 1):

To center an inline level element like `<img>` tag, you can set `text-align:center;` on the container, with your example:

```css
#logo {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="logo">
  <img src="logo.png" alt="Image of Traffic Monsoon">
</div>
```

In addition, remove `<center>`, it has been deprecated. And add following lines to make the image to shrink to fit automatically when its intrinsic width is larger than the container:

```
#logo img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your whole page in a `<main>` element, or a `wrapper` class. Set your `max-width` on that element, and all subsequent elements can have `width:100%` set.

Answer (score -1):

Please try this:

First of all wrap you entire page with a `div` named wrapper.

```
<div class="wrapper">your code here</div>
```

Then apply this `css` below:

```
.wrapper {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 1574px;
}

#logo {
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    width: 1331px;
}

#logo img{
    text-align: center;
    width: 96%;
}
```